# Can't install Bitcoin

Tags: installation

I have a laptop with Windows8.1
Intel Core i3 2.60 GHz
64-bit OS x64-based processor
4 GB memory
584 GB free space

Bitcoin Core minimum recommended is
Windows 7/8.x
1 GB memory
80 GB disk space

Downloaded Bitcoin Core and attempted to install and I get the message “Incompatible Program”

What can I do to install the program or get a compatible program?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus or anti-malware running? Make sure you downloaded the windows version and disable any anti-virus.

Answer (score 1):

download it from the official website :

https://bitcoin.org/en/download

for windows 64 bit:  https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.13.1/bitcoin-0.13.1-win64-setup.exe